# proxmox CT external vnc access

Tags: virtualization, paas, openvz, proxmox, novnc

I'm creating a PAAS provider with openVZ virtual machines on proxmox.
I want to use noVNC to access the instances in another website different than proxmox console.
I used an url with this form

> wss://promox_ip:8006/api2/json/nodes/node_name/openvz/instance_id/vncwebsocket?port=5900&vncticket=vnc_ticket

I'm always getting this error:`

> connection closed unexpectedly.

`
note that i use a new ticket each connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by adding modifications to HTTPerver.pm file under

> /usr/share/perl5/PVE/

to Allow accessing novnc console when not logged in.
Then send POST resquest to

> /api2/json/nodes/{node}/lxc/{vmid}/vncproxy

and get ticket and port.
Then you can connect via websocket to this link

> /api2/json/nodes/{node}/lxc/{vmid}/vncwebsocket